# How many crew quarters did Voyager have?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

How many crew quarters did Voyager have? I remember the episode where the Klingon ship self-destructed and the entire crew was transported aboard Voyager and most of the crew if not the entire crew had to double up on quarters.

Comment: @Richard: Are you working on an answer?

Comment: This [fan-made](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/uss-voyager-ncc-74656-sheet-1.jpg) suggests that there's capacity for an additional 80. Note that to the best of my knowledge, no-one from Paramount was directly involved with Kennedy Shipyards

Comment: "...the entire crew had to double up on quarters" Every crew member got a Klingon in their quarters? ;)

Comment: @RobertF - That sounds like the 5-second pitch for the **best.sitcom.ever**

Comment: Actually there was evidence of sharing quarters. In the episode Good Shephard you see some crewmen sleeping in bunk beds, indicating that they have at least one roommate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Startrek.com page on the [USS Voyager](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/voyager) states that an Intrepid-class ship is expected to have a complement of 200 crew.

> *An Intrepid-class vessel **capable of holding 200 crew members**, the
>   U.S.S. Voyager NCC-74656 is one of the fastest and most powerful
>   starships in Starfleet.*

In the episode "[The 37's](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/119.htm)", Janeway states that there are 152 crew on board, apparently including the Macquis, Neelix and Kes in her count.

> **JANEWAY:** *We have one hundred and fifty two men and women on this ship. What happens if half of them decide to stay on the planet? Could
>   we operate Voyager with seventy five crew members?*

---

Since there's no evidence of [officers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152646/how-many-people-on-voyager-outrank-harry-kim) sharing quarters on the Voyager, I think we can reasonably assume that there are at least 50 or so spare beds from a grand total of 200.

If half the crew volunteered to share quarters (freeing up a further 75 sets of quarters) that would leave 125 rooms for 200-ish Klingons, some of whom were already in family groups who'd want to be quartered together.

Comment: With 152 crew members they probably didn't need to double up, but if the ship had a full complement then junior officers and crew probably would have, just like on the Enterprise. Toss in a few more staterooms for visitors and the number of rooms probably range around 175.

Comment: @Xantec - The Voyager is "*Superbly equipped for exploration and research,*". My guess is that unlike the Enterprise, they would have very little spare capacity for additional rooms.

Comment: If you're exploring then there is the possibility of first contact which may mean visiting dignitaries, and you'd want them to have their own room.

Comment: @Xantec Probably not; they'd actually _avoid_ contact with such a small ship. Remember the TNG episode of the same name? First contact is a big deal, with long drawn out plans, and multiple simultaneous fact-finding missions. A ship as small as the _Intrepid_-class may explore and find planets of interest, but it would be left to the big boys to actually make contact. The Federation doesn't go straight from "finding new species" to "hosting dignitaries".

Comment: @Xantec - I agree. You'd definitely want a half-dozen *very nice rooms* set aside for guests.

Comment: Your math is off. For 152 people to free up 75 sets of quarters they'd *all* have to double up except the Captain and First Officer. If only half of the 152 people share, that's 76 people sharing who would need 38 rooms, and 76 people each in their own room, for a total of 114 occupied by crew, leaving about 86 rooms free for the Klingons if they started with 200.

Comment: @DM - 150 crew = 150 bedrooms. If half the crew agreed to share *with the other half*, there would be 75 bedrooms in use.

Comment: @Valorum So half volunteer to share, and the other half... volunteer to be shared with? Regardless, they're *all* sharing at that point.

Answer (score 1):

My best answer would have to be... Since only senior officers get their own quarters and we see 7 of them in the Ready Room briefings minus  Kess and Nelix, who aren't bridge officers. So first shift senior officers are Janeway, Chakotay, Tuvok, Harry Kim, and Tom Paris.Then 5 more (for night shift) totaling 12 then that leaves 140 who share quarters making the total of crew quarters 82.

Comment: We see no evidence of quarter sharing on Voyager.

Comment: @Valorum: Watch "Good Shepherd" again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Among officers, I mean. Who potentially make up [about half the crew](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/152649/20774). It's possible that about 50 of the crew are sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Voyager's, Intrepid class vessels typically had a crew complement of 140-160. Officer's get their own quarters, enlisted must share in a dual apartment setting. 
The Only major blueprints of Intrepid class deckplans are produced by fandom designers, Unlike Rick Sternbach who did Enterprise D. But never the less using it as a reference, Voyager I counted 155 sets of crew quarter rooms, Enough to provide quarters for everyone aboard Voyager without the need to share, assuming 80% are diverted for enlisted crew members who have to share, that's 124 sets of quarters that's enough for 279 personnel.
[image]

Comment: Don't forget that when you use someone else's picture, you need to cite where it's from.